# $x$ to $f(x)$ chart using MathJax (LaTeX)?

Tags: support, mathjax

Is it possible to do a simple x-y table in MathJax for Math StackExchange questions? Something like this:

[image]

I admit it would probably be a waste of time for most questions, but I'm sure it could have some applications.

Comment: See also http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4240/how-do-i-insert-a-table-when-asking-a-question, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6734/how-can-i-put-a-table-here and other posts shown there among linked questions.

Answer (score 5):

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
x & y \\\hline
-2 & -8\\\hline
-1 & -6.5\\\hline
0 & -5\\\hline
1 & -3.5\\\hline
2 & -2\\\hline
\end{array}$$

Code:

```
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
x & y \\\hline
-2 & -8\\\hline
-1 & -6.5\\\hline
0 & -5\\\hline
1 & -3.5\\\hline
2 & -2\\\hline
\end{array}$$
```

Comment: @Zack: As a purely cosmetic note, replacing `|c|c|` with `|r|l|` in this markup duplicates the alignment in your image. There are many other options as you might imagine.

Comment: Any ideas on coloring the first row?

Comment: @boywholived: [I try to avoid using colors.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4195/on-the-use-of-color-in-equations) So no idea about that.